# Handling a this.$router.replace(href); in vue 2

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am new to vue and working on vue code those before me created.  So there is a lot of legacy code that is just too complex to change right now.

The vue code can be in one of two states when a user wants to navigate to DynamicReport, they might be on that component or might not.  The problem I am trying to solve is that when the user is on DynamicReport and the code does a push, it gets the NavigationDuplicated error.  I have changed the code to do a replace, but that doesn't fire the mounted handler.  So I am trying to figure out how to reinitialize the component when the user wants to navigate to the new report.

This is in the App.vue:

```
      viewReportNotification: function(report) {
        const { href } = this.$router.resolve({
          name: 'DynamicReportWithId',
          params: { reportResultsId: report.reportResultsId } // Route parameters
        });

        console.log(`this.$route.path: ${this.$route.path}`)
        console.log(`href: ${href}`)
        if (this.$route.path !== href) {
          if (this.$route.path.startsWith('/DynamicReport/')) {
            console.log(`trying to replace: ${href}`)
            this.$router.replace(href);
          } else {
            console.log(`trying to PUSH: ${href}`)
            this.$router.push(href);
          }
        }
      },
```

And I tried adding this to the component, but the `beforeRouteUpdate` isn't being called:

```
  beforeRouteUpdate: function(to, from, next) {
    console.log(`beforeRouteUpdate( ${to}, ${from}, ...)`);
    if (to.type === 'replace') {
      console.log(`replacing ${from} with ${to}`);
      this.loadReportIfQueryParamsExist();
    }
    next();
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.loadReportIfQueryParamsExist();
    this.handlePanelOpen();
  },
```

Again, I am new to vue code, I am sure there is a lot better ways to do the whole thing, but...  I am just trying to fix a bug, not redesign the whole thing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different approach...  The mount calls another method, so now viewReportNotification() calls that other method and then calls replace to update the URL.  Works like a charm.  Thanks for the suggestions, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Since You are trying to kind of navigate to the same page, this issue is happening. What you can do is since you know that you need to push/replace to the same URL, you can try to reload the component so as this will re-run the mounted life cycle (Also since you mentioned legacy I am assuming you are using vue 2)

You can try using ->

```
vm.$forceUpdate();
```

Here vm is the Vue instance

Another **preferable** method would be to componentize the report view and use key and simply change it to re-render the component and this way the child component (here the reports component) will get re-rendered.

```
<template>
  <report-component :key="componentKey" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      componentKey: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    forceRerender() {
      this.componentKey += 1;  
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now you can call the **forceRerender()** method whenever the query changes and thus re-run the mounted method